# Comparing two variables in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, binaryfiles

I am having some trouble comparing two variables, hope someone could help.

Basically what i do is:

```
printf("\n\n +* Introduza o %d Prato:", i + 1);

scanf("%s", &pratos_novo->prato);

ver=verifica_prato(pratos_novo->prato);
  if(ver == 1)
/*PROCESS*/
```

I put M1 when asked because the it does exist in .bin file

function call:

```
int verifica_prato(char* p) {

    k = (struct item*) malloc(sizeof(item));
        while((fread(k, 1, sizeof(item), f)) != NULL) {
            if((*k).id == p){
                fclose(f);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

My goal is to return 1 when i put M1.

struct item:

```
struct item{
    char id[5];
    int ing[10];
    float qtd[10];
};
```

The problem is here : `(*k).id==p)`, the values are never the same, and I am 100% sure that M1 does exist in the .bin file.

Comment: (1) `while((fread(k,1,sizeof(item),f))!=NULL){` fread() does not return a pointer. (2) `if((*k).id==p){`. The shorthand for this is `if ( k->id==p)` , and (3) p is a pointer, so you'll need strcmp() /memcmp() , as others have said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing pointers when you need to compare strings.

Replace `if((*k).id==p)` with `if( strcmp( (*k).id, p) == 0 )` to compare the strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
if((*k).id==p)
```

You are only comparing two pointers, use `strcmp` function to compare two strings.